# Send mail after publish post on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm writing a function to send mails after i publish a post on my site but the problem is the following:

If i edit a post that's already published sends a new mail everytime i update a published post.

This is the function i wrote:

```
function send_mails($post_ID)  {
     global $wpdb;
     $post = get_post($post_ID);
     if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_ID ) ) {
         $contenido = $post->post_content;
         $excerpt = substr($contenido,0,255);
         $permalink = get_permalink($post_ID);
         $authorURL = get_author_posts_url($post->post_author);
         $title = $post->post_title;
                 $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_subscribe", ARRAY_A);
         $origen = "XXXX";
         $headers = "From: $origen\r\n";
         $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP5\n";
         $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
         $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
         foreach($result as $row){
               // A lot of code for styling the mail-..
         mail($row['email'],$title,$contenido,$headers);
         }
     }
     return $post_ID;
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'send_mails' );
```

What can be wrong? Or maybe i missing some function to check if it's an edited post?

Thank you in advance

Comment: a new post wouldn't be a revision...

Comment: I though that too.. But every time i update a post that's already on the site, sends another mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a meta value to the post when the email is sent:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'email_sent', 'yes', true)
```

Then check for this in the send email function so it will only send once.

```
if( get_post_meta($post_id, 'email_sent', 'true') != 'yes' ) {
    //    send the email
   }
```

Comment: That's the answer i was looking for. Thank you !

Comment: Without the $post->post_status == 'published' doesn't send a mail when the draft is saved

Answer (score 0):

save_post is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email. The data for the post is stored in $_POST, $_GET or the global $post_data, depending on how the post was edited. For example, quick edits use $_POST.

add_action( 'save_post', 'function' );

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Answer (score 0):

To update answer for new guys.

Use save_post, which from WordPress 3.3 has third parameter "update". So example would be:

```
function save_func($ID, $post,$update) {

   if($update == false) {
     // do something if its first time publish
   } else {
     // Do something if its update
   }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_func', 10, 3 );
```

Thats it.